# Does consistent estimators have in-variance property?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

If $(T_n)$ is a sequence of consistent estimators of a parameter $\theta$ ( i.e. for every $ \epsilon >0$ , $\lim_{n \to \infty} P [ \space |T_n -\theta|< \epsilon ]=1$ ) , then is it true that for any continuous function $f$ , $f(T_n)$ is a sequence of consistent estimators of $f(\theta)$ ?

Comment: Seems like the definition of continuity of $f$ at $\theta$, no?

Comment: @Did: How ? it is interms of probability ...

Comment: It is, probably (whatever you mean by "it"). And?

Comment: @SouvikDey see Did's response. If you can bound the domain of $f$ within $\epsilon$ then, by the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition of continuity, this implies that your function is bounded within  $\delta$, with both going to zero as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, thus your function will converge in probability to the true value.

Answer (score 3):

$$\forallϵ\gt0,\quad\exists\alpha\gt0,\quad[|T_n−θ|<\alpha]\subseteq[|f(T_n)−f(θ)|<ϵ]$$